# Is it possible to redeclare a variable as a different type?

Tags: objective-c

```
@protocol BGTableViewDelegateMother <BGIhaveNavigationController>



@end

@interface BGTableViewDelegateMother : NSObject
@property (weak,nonatomic) UITableView * tv;
@property id <BGIhaveNavigationController> delegate;
@end
```

Say latter I want to inherit BGTableViewDelegateMother.

However, I want to change the type of delegate into something else. Maybe not  but . Is it possible?

Of course BGIhaveNavigationControllerandsomeotherthing inherits from BGIhaveNavigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the protocol to which the delegate of your subclass conforms incorporates the BGIhaveNavigationController protocol it's fine.  You can do something like this:

```
@protocol BGIhaveNavigationControllerAndSomethingElse <BGIhaveNavigationController>
- (void)somethingElse;
@end

@interface BGTableViewDelegateChild : BGTableViewDelegateMother
@property id <BGIhaveNavigationControllerAndSomethingElse> delegate;
@end
```

Note that if BGIhaveNavigationControllerAndSomethingElse was declared like

```
@protocol BGIhaveNavigationControllerAndSomethingElse <NSObject>
```

(that is, not incorporating BGIhaveNavigationController) then the compiler would complain about `BGIhaveNavigationController`'s delegate's type.

Comment: for the delegate property do you mean <BGIhaveNavigationControllerandsomethingelse>  ?

Comment: @pnizzle: Yes, I'm making a lot of typos tonight…  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, im not picking on you, im just trying to understand the question from your answer!